# How to add a custom application into a wordpress openshift cartrige

Tags: wordpress, git, customization, openshift

I have created an application on Openshift adding a Wordpress cartridge which I have also installed my plugins and themes.

That is all right, but now I would like to add some custom application to my domain. I have already uploaded my custom application with "git push" to my Openshift application.

Now I realised that my default Wordpress cartridge is located in `app-root/repo/php/` and my custom application is in `app-deployments/current/repo/php/`.

When I access my website through my browser I access my Wordpress website which is located in `app-root/repo/php/` but I would to know how to also access my custom application which is in `app-deployments/current/repo/php`.

So when user access `http://app-name-domain.rhcloud.com/` the server brings the wordpress website and when user access `http://app-name-domain.rhcloud.com/my-custom-application`, the server should bring him my custom application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add another application to the same gear as your wordpress blog, then you should do a custom wordpress installation instead of using the wordpress openshift quickstart.  That quickstart does some trickery in the background to download wordpress, install it, and do some symlinks to run it.  You would be best off setting everything up custom in your php directory in your git repo and running it yourself the way you are describing how you want it to run.